# Continuous but nowhere differentiable example

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, derivatives

I am trying to prove that

$$f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos(10^n\pi x)}{2^n}$$

is an example of a continuous but nowhere differentiable function.

I know that this is an example of a Weirstrass function, but I am trying to do the proof by hand, and I have what I think should be most of the proof but cannot see how to conclude it.

In particular, I have proved that for any integers $j,k$, $k \geq 1$,

$$ \left|f\left(\frac{j+1}{10^k}\right) - f\left(\frac{j}{10^k}\right)\right| > 2^{-k}$$

It seems to me this should be enough to conclude that $f$ is not differentiable. Help please!